# How do I integrate $\int\sec^5(x)\space dx?$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I go from the integral of $\sec^5(x)\space dx$

to $\frac{1}{4} \sec^3 (x)\tan x+  \frac{3}{4}\int\sec^3 (x)\space dx?$

Answer (score 4):

Integrate by parts:

$$\int dx \, \sec^5{x} = \int dx \, \sec^2{x} \, \sec^3{x} = \tan{x} \sec^3{x} - 3 \int dx \, \tan^2{x} \sec^3{x} $$

which in turn is, using $\sec^2=1+\tan^2$

$$\int dx \, \sec^5{x} = \tan{x} \sec^3{x} - 3 \int dx \, \sec^5{x} + 3 \int dx \, \sec^3{x}$$

or

$$\int dx \, \sec^5{x} = \frac14 \tan{x} \sec^3{x}  + \frac{3}{4} \int dx \, \sec^3{x}$$